# Unable to properly read CLI flag

Tags: go

As stated in the title, I'm not able to properly print `-e` flag value`test@test.com`.

This is my code so far:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var email string
    flag.StringVar(&email, "e", "", "email")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Println(email)
}
```

After running with `go run test.go -e=test@test.com` I get `test@test` output.

**How do I get "test@test.com"?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it in single quotation marks so the shell leave it as it is

```
go run test.go '-e=test@test.com'
```